#  Developer Program is pending

Tags: development, developer-program

it's been 2 days since I bought the Apple Developer Program, and my account is pending:
[image: Account is pending]

About 10 minutes after the enrollment, I got an email, telling me that my purchase was being processed.

1 hour after I got this email, I got another email about the taxes, and there was a PDF attached to it.

I checked my account on Apple's website, but apparently, my account wasn't activated.

They say it should take 48 hours, but there is still nothing.  In addition to this post, I contacted  Developer support, they should answer me soon.

How long does it take for an account to be validated? Does it take longer if you're not in the U.S.?

Comment: Can you edit the question to mention if you enrolled as an individual or an organisation?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I don't think so, but what was your plan?

Comment: Individual enrollment is generally instantaneous. Enrolling as an organisation may take a couple working days as Apple verifies the organisation at its end.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I enrolled as an individual

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend [contacting](http://developer.apple.com/contact) Apple Developer.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Ok, that's what I did

Comment: This is basically a support question which is better addressed to Apple Developer Support directly.

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325926/how-long-does-it-take-to-enroll-in-the-developer-program-organisation. @nohillside is correct  that if you have paid for this service, just call or contact Apple store support to escalate and check on the delivery of the service you ordered. That process is no different than ordering a phone and asking when it will ship.